# optimistic lock or pessimistic lock?

Tags: database, locking

In my application , whenever i update a record in DB, i use a query like :
udapte set ... from mytable **where status='normal'**;

There is a field in mytable called as status which will take normal/cancel as a value if a record is inserted/deleted.

Now when i am concurrently doing a query on mytable specifically, it is working fine , concurrency is being handled (with three person remotely accessing) . but now i am wondering which type of lock is it ?
optimistic or pessimistic or neither of them.

going through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control has added to the doubts i already had because i am not registering timestamp !

Comment: What RDBMS?      .______

Comment: @usr the RDBMS is  oracle

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario concurrency is not being handled.  User1 could overwrite User2's data without ever seeing or knowing about User2's update.

Optimistic locking is where you use something construct like a `RowVersion` on the record.  What happens is that User1 gets the record and RowVersion, then User2 gets the record in second later.  User1 updates the record and the `RowVersion` increments to say 2.  User2 attempts to update the record but cannot because his/her RowVersion is old.

User1

```
 UPDATE record
    SET status = 'test', RowVersion = 2
    WHERE RowVersion = 1;
```

User2

```
 UPDATE record
    SET status = 'test2', RowVersion = 2
    WHERE RowVersion = 1;
```

This statement results in zero records affected because the RowVersion changed to 2.

Comment: don't u think we are achieving the same by using `status=normal` , it's kind of similar to using the rowversion (at least going by the concept ). what 's ur opinion ?